# Could this wall material contain asbestos?

Tags: asbestos

I'm new here and I guess it's not the greatest thing to be asking, but any thoughts if this wall material could have asbestos in it? I'm really not sure what this wall material is. Thank you to everyone in advance!

[image]

[Shared Album of wall material](https://goo.gl/photos/eAvSpib9txiGmGAF7)

Answer (score 4):

Nope. It's fiberboard. And, it's too late anyway as your lungs are now already permanently damaged if it were...a warning to all that you should always wear a dust mask (preferably N95 grade) for any demolition work. And Yes, dust-off, brush-off, blow-off or shake-out your hair and clothes only upon reaching the outdoors.

Comment: Don't feel dumb. There were an amazing variety of products that contained asbestos. One asbestos product looks very similar to yours, but it's very white inside overall.

Comment: yea, this is all brown on the inside and back, with only the front being white.

Comment: Yep, you're mostly good. It does likely have formaldehyde & should be removed & then cut up or broken up outside. The formaldehyde has  mostly off gassed but opening it up can release some minor VOC's. Doing it outside just means less airing out of the house, if you give a crap...it's no worse than new carpet or paint.

Comment: No problem & thank you, especially for pictures. Your question is probably on many other people's minds & this will be extremely helpful.

Comment: +1 This stuff is not generally available as a building material any longer, largely having been replaced by drywall. It is often called *beaverboard* after one of the early manufacturers (Beaverboard is actually  trademark). It was also known as Upson Board, Cornell board, Sterling,  and Fibro-Wallboard. While it is a form of fiberboard, is should not be confused with MDF or HDF, both much denser material.

Comment: I've seen the Upson & Cornell stamps, but I hadn't heard of the other names. I've had great results with MDF for the bases of baseboard assemblies & wainscoting. But, I stay away from that & any particle board otherwise. Plywood, not OSB, is the only worthy go to product, if a glass smooth surface isn't needed.

Comment: At least in the UK, "sterling board" is a name for OSB, not fibreboard.